# How to make a Parent Category a menu item in Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, articles, joomla3, section, categories

I migrated a Joomla 1.5 site to Joomla 3 and the *sections* properly became parent *categories*. But when I try to create a menu item with that parent category it says

> Warning: Save failed with the following error: Another menu item with the same parent has this alias.

However, there is no menu item with that alias.

That parent category has its own article (some text and a few images). How can I make it such that when I click on the menu item for that parent category (which I can't) that "article" appears?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, really. I know how to create a menu and menu items... what I want to know is why I can't create  menu item with a Parent Category.

Comment: I think there must be alias available. can you please check again?

Answer (score 1):

The alias must be unique.

If you can't find the conflicting item, also remember to check the trash.